# jshint active in emacs via flymode, but does not produce any output

Tags: emacs, jshint

I have install jshint and i checked it on the sample file from the bash and it works.

Now, when I open .js file in emacs and go to the flymake-mode, I get the message jshint server has started on 127.0.0.13003. Now, when I enter this obviously wrong line of code

```
var var0 = 10    // which is OK
varnx var1 = 10; // which is wrong
```

jshint just sits there and does not warn me.

Thank you!